# Configure HttpRealIpModule for nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to add Cloudflare on the server i will receive in some days. However to preserve my visitors IP, I will have to install HttpRealIpModule module as per Cloudflare wiki --
https://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Nginx

I use these EPEL repository,

```
rpm --import https://fedoraproject.org/static/0608B895.txt
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
rpm --import http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi 
rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
yum install yum-priorities
```

and then

```
yum install nginx
```

I have two questions,

1. Will these install the HttpRealIpModule automatically
2. If not how can i install it with these EPEL repositories

Comment: The above commands only enable 3rd party repositories that may contain the nginx module and do not install the module itself.

Comment: That's what i also think i need confirmation whether these repo contain the HttpRealIpModule Or not

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But you can compile nginx from source and enable that module with this compile option --with-http_realip_module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of nginx provided in the remi repository already includes the HttpRealIpModule. You only need to `yum install nginx`.

You can check what nginx was compiled with using `nginx -V`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.0.15
built by gcc 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt=-Wl,-E
```

Comment: Thank so much Micheal .........That's all i wanted to know